# Side effects of redefining $stdout and $stderr in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, stdout, stderr

I'd like to temporarily redirect `$stdout` and `$stderr` to a file in a script that will be run by `script/runner` in a Rails app. Are there any potential side effects to doing so? Will changing the global variable cause the output streams to be redirected in other parts of the Rails application during the duration of my script? What about other libraries or threads used by the script?

Comment: Would this [discussion](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/102759) help you in your situation? Having something like 'tee'?

Comment: @emboss: In a more general case maybe, but in my case I'll be running the script as a cron job, so I want _all_ output suppressed and redirected to a file.

Comment: OK, I see, you *want* the output to be suppressed, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard output and standard error streams are generally accessible in two ways each:

- `$stdout` and `STDOUT`
- `$stderr` and `STDERR`

A sufficiently clever person could also open their own copies using [`IO.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000889) with a file descriptor argument:

```
sneaky = IO.new(2, 'w')
```

And now you have writable access to the standard error stream through `sneaky` without having anything to do with `$stderr` or `STDERR`.

Reassigning `$stderr` and `$stdout` should work fine unless something in your code, your gems, or Ruby itself is using the constants (`STDOUT`, `STDERR`) or is accessing the streams directly through C's stdio, unix's low level `read`/`write` with numeric file descriptors or is opening their own access to the streams using `IO.new`. I haven't dug into the source but I doubt assigning to `$stdout` will do anything to `stdout` in C-land or file descriptor 1 in Unix-land.

If you really need to trap the standard output and error streams then you're probably better off writing a wrapper shell script to redirect the streams for you.

---

**UPDATE**: If you're mostly (only?) concerned about changing `$stdout` and `$stderr` inside your `script/runner` bleeding into the rest of your Rails app then you don't have to worry about that. Each process — your `script/runner` process and however many server processes your main application has running — gets its own set of globals so you can change them all you want in your script without making a mess of your main application. Of course, you still have to worry about gems using `STDOUT` instead of `$stderr` or using `IO.new` to get their own private standard out.

Comment: Interesting, that's helpful. But I'm still curious if reassigning the global variables will affect other code or threads (even if that solution doesn't capture 100% of the output).

Comment: @jrdioko: Reassigning should do the Right Thing for other threads as threads share all the global state. Processes on the other hand...

Comment: I guess that was my main question. If a script is started with `script/runner` and that script changes global variables, will the change interfere with other parts of the running Rails application, or will that be isolated to the script and its own threads?

Comment: @jrdioko: `script/runner` will use its own process (as will the console) so it will have its own globals.

Answer (score 2):

I typically run all my cron jobs through a [wrapper script](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/blob/master/lib/generators/vulcanize/templates/base/script/cron-sh) which saves stdout/err and prints it all iff the subprocess exits with a non-zero error code (so I get an email from cron on failure).

Comment: Good idea. (But the link is broken)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on what other gems you use, how is your logging and server start configured. I guess, a follow up question is, why do you need that? Probably there's a better way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Well, for the sake of this question, let's say no extra gems and everything is set up as default. I need to do it because I'm trying to write a small cron job framework that will capture all output created by another class (regardless of how it's sent to `STDOUT` or `STDERR`) and log it to a file.